# How to use a RowFilter on a DataTable to find rows where a column is both not null and greater than/less than a value?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, rowfilter

I'm trying to filter a DataTable of x, y, z coordinate values within a certain range for each of them. For example, I want to see the rows with an x value greater than 200. My issue is that the DataTable is read in from a DataGridView and all of the fields are interpreted as strings. Additionally, several rows are missing at least one x, y, or z value, so I want to exclude those.

As a test on just the x values, I've tried

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "[X Value] 
IS NOT NULL AND CONVERT([X Value], 'System.Decimal') > 200.0";
```

and this results in the error message "Input string was not in a correct format." I assume this is happening because it's trying to convert a null value into a decimal. I get the same issue when the row filter does not include the `[X Value] IS NOT NULL` half.

Is it possible to do this all in a single RowFilter?

Comment: Are you sure that all not null values in the X column are convertible to decimal according to your locale settings?

Comment: Are you sure the DataColumn is a type which requires converting?

Comment: @Steve yes, I know that my non-null values are in an acceptable decimal format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the AND ensures that if the first condition is not met, the second condition is not evaluated. So the error is not caused by a null value, but with great probability by an empty string.

Just change your test to

```
"[x value] IS NOT NULL AND [x value] <> '' AND CONVERT([x value], 'System.Decimal') > 200.0";
```

Comment: Ahh, I see! I had been assuming that checking `[X Value] IS NOT NULL` was the same as `[X Value] <> ''`, but now I see the difference for null values and empty strings. I changed my rowfilter to `"TRIM([X Value]) <> '' AND CONVERT([X Value], 'System.Decimal') > 200.0"` and that worked. Thanks!